Allocate more memory to Ubuntu
I'm having 2 OS installed on my DELL laptop: Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, each takes 50% memory of my hard disk. Now I want to increase that of Ubuntu. Is there a way to do that?

You are not talking about memory.  You are talking about disk space.   A hard disk doesn't have memory.  It has disk space. (Note: if you use the wrong words, you will get misleading / irrelevant hist when you search for answers.) And this is not a programming question.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.  Ask on https://askubuntu.com

Thanks for your answer
